# Is it possible to extract the variable from constant in lua

Tags: lua

> I am really noob in lua so i might be asking impossible stuffs so sorry for that

So what i want to know is that , if there's a way to know which variable contains the value of my desire in lua
Example ->

```
variable[1] = "1.0"
variable[2] = "2.0"
print("variable with 1.0 value")
```